# Filter list of inner lists by one element of each inner list

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to extract/store in a list all the values e.g. '55095571@NO2' and '25613911@N00' that are attached to 'Not shown' & 'Unknown'.

```
index  type  size  value

0  list 2     ['Not shown', '55095571@N02']
1  list 2     ['Dublin, Ireland', '87036731@N04']
2  list 2     ['Dublin, Ireland', '87036731@N04']
3  list 2     ['Teddington, UK', '12220922@N05']
4  list 2     ['Peterborough (UK)', '91415433@N03']
5  list 2     ['Dublin, Ireland', '87036731@N04']
6  list 2     ['Unknown', '34305619@N06']
7  list 2     ['Unknown', '99902388@N04']
8  list 2     ['Unknown', '25613911@N00']
```

Any help or advice would be great!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Posting a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be great... of code you tried that creates those partial lists and your code to extract the data that does not work for you ...

Comment: what is `0 list 2 ` or `8 list 2`

Comment: Is this a list of lists or something exotic I've never come across? Because the format you've represented your data in doesn't make that clear at all.

Comment: Apologies it is a list of strings.

Comment: This [list-comprehension-vs-lambda-filter](/questions/3013449/list-comprehension-vs-lambda-filter) is a kind-a dupe ... with general infos about lambda/list comp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [filter(function, iterable)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) to filter iterables. The function has to return `True` for the values you want. I pass a [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=lambda#lambda) function that returns `True` if the first element of the list is in the ones you wanted.

I combined your output back into a list to operate on:

```
data = [ ['Not shown', '55095571@N02']
       , ['Dublin, Ireland', '87036731@N04']
       , ['Dublin, Ireland', '87036731@N04']
       , ['Teddington, UK', '12220922@N05']
       , ['Peterborough (UK)', '91415433@N03']
       , ['Dublin, Ireland', '87036731@N04']
       , ['Unknown', '34305619@N06']
       , ['Unknown', '99902388@N04']
       , ['Unknown', '25613911@N00']]

# filter all that have the desired 1st param from the data  
codes = list( filter( lambda x: x[0] in ['Not shown','Unknown'],data))

for t,c in codes: 
    print(c)  # just print coords

# extract coords in seperate list
c = [d[1] for d in codes]

# print list
print(c)
```

Output:

```
55095571@N02
34305619@N06
99902388@N04
25613911@N00

['55095571@N02', '34305619@N06', '99902388@N04', '25613911@N00']
```